# React-router-dom doesn't work (renders only a blank page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have installed react-router-dom^6.1.0 in my project, but nothing is rendering (I see only blank screen when starting project). Here is the code:

```
    import './main.global.css'
import {Container, Div} from './styles'
import { Header } from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import RouterView from './routes'

import AboutPage from "./pages/AboutPage";
import CalendarPage from "./pages/CalendarPage";
import LibraryPage from "./pages/LibraryPage";
import MainPage from './pages/MainPage'
import MediaPage from "./pages/MediaPage";
import PrizePage from "./pages/PrizePage";
import ProjectsPage from "./pages/ProjectsPage";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Div>
        <Header />
        <Container>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' exact element={<MainPage />} />
              <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage />} />
              <Route path='/library' element={<LibraryPage />} />
              <Route path='/projects' element={<ProjectsPage />} />
              <Route path='/prize' element={<PrizePage />} />
              <Route path='/media' element={ <MediaPage />} />
              <Route path='/calendar' element={<CalendarPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </Div>
    </Router>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `exact` prop from your first route will fix the problem.

Since react-router-dom v6, there is no need to pass the `exact` prop.
By default, react router will always look for the exact path we pass.

So, your code should look like this:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <Div>
        <Header />
        <Container>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<MainPage />} />
              <Route path='/about' element={<AboutPage />} />
              <Route path='/library' element={<LibraryPage />} />
              <Route path='/projects' element={<ProjectsPage />} />
              <Route path='/prize' element={<PrizePage />} />
              <Route path='/media' element={ <MediaPage />} />
              <Route path='/calendar' element={<CalendarPage />} />
            </Routes>
        </Container>
        <Footer />
      </Div>
    </Router>
  );
```